# Redis Default Config Not Found

Tags: redis, installation, server, redis-server

I'm following this tutorial to setup a Redis server:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-redis

and getting this error message:

```
Mmmmm... the default config is missing. Did you switch to the utils directory?
```

I'm in the /utils directory, but there doesn't appear to be a default config. From the documentation I've read online, it seems like the config should have been created upon setup. Is this something I have to make manually or is this an installation error? My 'make test' command ran successfully, so I don't know why the config file wouldn't have been set up automatically.

Comment: What version of ubuntu are you using? I had the same problem. I was following an installation tutorial of Ubuntu 14.04. For Ubuntu 16.04 you may copy the configuration file redis.conf from the place you made the 'untar' to /etc/redis in order to work

Answer (score 1):

If you're on WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux), you can get this error if you put your Redis folder somewhere that has a path name containing whitespace.

So, like if you put it in the "Program Files" folder. I migrated mine out to just the `C:\` drive (or `/mnt/c/` for WSL), and it worked just fine.

Comment: Note: I did copy my redis.conf file out to `/etc/redis/` and into the `utils/` folder, but the code is looking to step _back_ out of the `utils/` folder to find that config. From looking at the script, I'm not sure I needed to copy it anywhere, just had that whitespace conflict in the path.

Answer (score 0):

Had to manually copy default config from the dir above into the correct dir.

Comment: What do you mean by from the dir above?

Comment: Copy what file? redis.conf?